# How to debug a macro that calculates distances between two points?

Tags: vba, google-api, xmlhttprequest

I have a macro that calculates distances between two points. I am unable to get it to work, and would like some help debugging it.

I have created a Google API key, and have incorporated that in as well, but for some reason the macro doesn't work

```
Public Function

GetDT(origin_city As String, _
origin_state As String, origin_country As String, _
destination_city As String, _
destination_state As String, destination_country As String _
)

Dim surl                As String
Dim oXH                 As Object
Dim bodytxt             As String

Dim distanc_e           As String


surl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=" 
& _
Replace(origin_city, " ", "+") & "+" & Replace(origin_state, " ", "+") & 
"+" & Replace(origin_country, " ", "+") & _
"&destinations=" & _
Replace(destination_city, " ", "+") & "+" & Replace(destination_state, " 
", "+") & "+" & Replace(destination_country, " ", "+") & _
"&mode=driving&units=metric&key=MY_KEY"


Set oXH = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")

With oXH
    .Open "get", surl, False
    .send
    bodytxt = .responseText
End With

bodytxt = Right(bodytxt, Len(bodytxt) - InStr(1, bodytxt, "<text>") - 5)
tim_e = Left(bodytxt, InStr(1, bodytxt, "</text>") - 1)


bodytxt = Right(bodytxt, Len(bodytxt) - InStr(1, bodytxt, "<text>") - 5)
distanc_e = Left(bodytxt, InStr(1, bodytxt, "</text>") - 1)

GetDT = distanc_e

Set oXH = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work... what does it do instead of working?  Does it give  a message, does the parent app crash, does it beep loudly and spew smoke out the back?

Comment: Gives a #VALUE! error (On the excel interface when i write the formula GetDT(......), not on the VBA interface), instead of the value of the distance between 2 points

Comment: So when run as a function within the VBA environment it returns the correct value, but when entered as a worksheet function it doesn't work - there's a lot of [limitations when using a UDF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel).  I think `Set oXH = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")` may come under that, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to confidently answer this question with the information provided.  Writing a separate function to create the url will make your code more testable.  Using `Option Explicit` to force all variables to be declared will detect any typos.

If `MY_KEY` is a variable then the url should look like this `"..metric&key=" & MY_KEY`.

> ```
> surl = GetDTURL(origin_city, origin_state, origin_country, destination_city, destination_state, destination_country)
> ```

```
Function GetDTURL(origin_city As String, origin_state As String, origin_country As String, destination_city As String, destination_state As String, destination_country As String)
    Dim surl As String
    Const BaseURl As String = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=@origin_city+@origin_state+@origin_country&destinations=@destination_city+@destination_state+@destination_country&mode=driving&units=metric&key=MY_KEY"
    surl = BaseURl
    surl = Replace(surl, "@origin_city", origin_city)
    surl = Replace(surl, "@origin_state", origin_state)
    surl = Replace(surl, "@origin_country", origin_country)
    surl = Replace(surl, "@destination_city", destination_city)
    surl = Replace(surl, "@destination_state", destination_state)
    surl = Replace(surl, "@destination_country", destination_country)
    surl = Replace(surl, " ", "+")
    GetDTURL = surl
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks @TinMan for taking the effort here.....1)MY_KEY is my API Key that i haven't pasted here........2) For this line of your code- (surl = Replace(" ", "+")), I got an error message - Compile error: Argument not optional.....Could you further help me>?

Comment: @Varun thanks.  I updated my code. I should have tested the function.

Comment: I am not getting the value of the distance, but this text : https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=Kochi+Kerala+India&destinations=Thrissur+Kerala+India&mode=driving&units=metric&key=A***SyC*F0***Ed*Jo*y*****GZ2********tZQw......Could you help me again? Thanks a ton:)

Comment: @Varun: the link you have provided here has corrupted, as is evident from your comment. Remember also that this maps endpoint may not show readers what it shows you, and it may also change over time. Ergo, it is necessary for you to explain what it shows and what is wrong with it. That information is probably best added to your question, at the end.

Comment: Thanks, I should have been more clear. The text message "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancem......." that you checked was an Excel output for the code written by @TinMan. The link is not corrupted, I changed the key as I wanted to keep it confidential. The purpose was to show that a link gets generated instead of a distance value being populated. Copying the link on my web page gives an accurate value of distance. It would be great if the value gets populated on an Excel interface directly, could you or TinMan modify the code written by him to make this happen? Thanks again

Comment: @halfer, The code in the main question gives a #VALUE! error (On the excel interface when i write the formula GetDT(......), not on the VBA interface), instead of the value of the distance between 2 points

Comment: @Varun please add the `responseText` to your post.

Comment: @Varun: your comment ("modify the code to make this happen") is what readers will often call "a request for free work". The question you should ask is "how can I fix it", not asking others to do it for you. Mindset is everything when programming - get into good habits!

Comment: @TinMan, thanks so much. The code now populates the distance between 2 points. I am new to VBA, This wouldn't have been possible without your help